# Raspberry Pi CM4 I/O board 2-layer PCB design

Tags: pcb-design, raspberry-pi, routing

I am a beginner in PCB designing, well in past experience, designed an PCB with some sort of digital signals, power (AC/DC) lines and USB.

Now I am working to design the PCB for CM4 I/O board with GPIOs, CSI, HDMI, USB-OTG, USB type-C, SD card connectors.

I am posting schematic and PCB layout here. Please suggest your inputs and issues in this, that can save me on cost and time. I am happy to incorporate that.

**Schematic for GPIO connector**

[image: GPIO connector]

**Schematic for high-speed signal connector**

[image: High speed connector]

**Overall PCB**

[image: PCB]

**USB signal routing**

[image: USB]

**CSI signal routing**

[image: CSI]

**HDMI signal routing**

[image: HDMI]

**Power and GPIO signal routing**

[image: GPIO]

As in a single image it is quite complicated to see, so I put the snapshot of different portion. Let me know if you need any other detail or info, I am ready to share.

PS: I have not filled the ground plane, so that the layout is clearly visible.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Soliciting schematic review input like this is very open-ended and perhaps opinionated.

Comment: High speed signal routing is new for me, so main focus of my problem is HDMI and CSI signal routing, have I done that correctly, or I have done some very common mistake ?

Comment: You really need a 4-layer board for this, there's no way your impedances are correct on a two layer board.